# AWS Codepipeline - Customer Managed Key is mandatory to accross account deploy in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-kms

When I try deploy to ECS in another account by Codepipeline, I receive this message:

***Unable to access the artifact with Amazon S3 object key 'xxxxxxxx/BuildArtif/yyyy'***

I realized that the reason is to use the default KMS. I would need to create a new Customer Managed Key and give permission to cross account.

Link 01: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html

Link 02: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66651760/5494849

The problem is:

The only artifact is the "imagedefinitions.json" created in Build stage and used in Deploy ECS stage and I don't need encrypt it and wouldn't like to pay 1 USD for a CMK that i don't need.

I figure out that i can't disable KMS in Codepipeline. Also, i tried check "Disable artifact encryption" in CodeBuild, but looks codepipeline overrides this configuration.

My next idea is: Create a new Code Build Project and replace my current ECS Deploy. I wouldn't need imagedefinitions.json artifact (i just will set output environment variables) and would do the deploy using aws cli (create a task definition revision and update service). But i really i dont know if this is a good idea.

Is there any other solution that I can't figure out?